# Chaquopy install pandas

Tags: android, pandas, gradle, artificial-intelligence, chaquopy

I am using Chaquopy in my android app, and when I try to install pandas using these lines in my build.gradle file:

```
pip {
                install "joblib"
                install "pandas==1.5.3"
}
```

, I get the warnings:

```
_Warning: Package 'pandas._libs.src' is absent from the `packages` configuration.
  !!
  
          ********************************************************************************
          ############################
          # Package would be ignored #
          ############################
          Python recognizes 'pandas._libs.src' as an importable package[^1],
          but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.
  
          This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to distribute this
          package, please make sure that 'pandas._libs.src' is explicitly added
          to the `packages` configuration field.
```

and the error:

```
Failed to install pandas==1.5.3 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/ee/146cab1ff6d575b54ace8a6a5994048380dc94879b0125b25e62edcb9e52/pandas-1.5.3.tar.gz#sha256=74a3fd7e5a7ec052f183273dc7b0acd3a863edf7520f5d3a1765c04ffdb3b0b1.
For assistance, please raise an issue at https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues.
  error: CCompiler.compile: Chaquopy cannot compile native code
```

Chaquopy version: `id 'com.chaquo.python' version '14.0.2' apply false`

Any help or guidance on how to resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated

I tried different versions of pandas, but I did not find a compatible one. I also tried to download the .whl file and use the path to it for installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newest pandas version supported by Chaquopy is currently 1.3.2 on Python 3.8, or 1.5.0 on Python 3.9 and 3.10.

To discover this, you could either remove the version number requirement and let pip automatically install the newest one available, or check the package repository [here](https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/pandas/).

Comment: thank you so much! it finally worked with Python 3.10 and pandas 1.5.0

Comment: Hi  mhsmith, thank you very much for building Chaquopy and also helping developers who use that SDK. Can you please look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77231899/how-to-i-install-the-latest-versions-of-numpy-which-are-available-as-whl-file) as well?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions (order of preference):

1. Upgrade or downgrade the pandas version that you're using
2. Use a different library that doesn't require native code
3. Use a pre-complied version of pandas by installing the pandas package using pip

   dependencies {
   python("org.pypi:pandas:1.5.3+non-native")
   }

Comment: If I understand correctly, the `python("org.pypi...` syntax is for pygradle. Chaquopy uses a different syntax which is described [here](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#android-requirements).